# Setting font DPI system-wide

Tags: debian, x11

I have recently installed Debian 11 with the desktop environment LXQt on a laptop with a 14 inch display. By default text and icons are tiny, so to get a reasonable text size I have set the DPI in `~/.Xresources` to `Xft.dpi: 144` (50 percent larger). As far as I understand there is no way to enlarge toolbar icons. Now I want to make the DPI setting system-wide so that also the login screen and other users have the same text size. The directory `/etc/X11/Xresources/` has one file named `x11-common`. Should I edit this file or add a new one? What is the convention? Are all files in `Xresources` read upon login?